# UITableView dynamic cell heights only correct after some scrolling when resizing cell according to uiimage view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic-resizing

[image]

As you can see in the 1st Image . No text visible in `UITableviewCell`. 
After I scroll it appears and resize the cell. I want to resize cell according to `UIImage`. I am fetching image  from API using `SDWebImage`. 
I am putting code I have done in UITableView Cell for row method .

```
cell.imgViewSlide.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: 
  self.arrSliderImage[indexPath.row]), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "HomeSliderImage"), options: .continueInBackground) { (image, error, type, url) in

let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds

let pixelWidth = Int((image?.size.width)!)

let pixelHeight = Int((image?.size.height)!)


let height = ((pixelHeight  * Int(screenBounds.width)) / pixelWidth)                                
cell.heightImage.constant = CGFloat(integerLiteral: height)                                  
                                }
```

I have applied plenty of solution but not working correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you are fetching the Images from dynamic URL using SDWebImage, Initially you need to set a static height for the image of your tableView Cell in the storyboard.

Define a **constraint Outlet** for this image height in your cell, and then you should define the height of the image according to the **aspect Ratio**.

```
cell.imgViewSlideHeight.constant = CGFloat((aspectRatio) * Double(self.frame.width))
```

Here `self` is the UITableViewCell reference and `imgViewSlideHeight` is the cell Image Height Constraint.